# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have successfully created a Single File Component in Vue; there are no compilation errors, however, when I attempt to view the component (by navigating to it's route link), the expected page is not displayed, and instead, I get a stack trace printed in the (Chrome) browser - using the Vue Devtools plugin.

Here is the stacktrace output in the Vue Devtools plugin console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: 
log.js?1afd:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'DockPanel'
    |     property '_layout' -> object with constructor 'DockLayout'
    --- property '_parent' closes the circle"

found in

---> <Demo> at src/components/Demo.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
merged @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3301
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6471
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
(anonymous) @ main.ts?bc82:8
./src/main.ts @ app.js:5941
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
fn @ app.js:130
1 @ app.js:6015
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
(anonymous) @ app.js:905
Show 11 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'DockPanel'
    |     property '_layout' -> object with constructor 'DockLayout'
    --- property '_parent' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Proxy.toString (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:94)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"4105b414-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Demo.vue?vue&type=template&id=09260093&scoped=true& (app.js:2401), <anonymous>:10:25)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3542)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462)
    at mountComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067)
    at VueComponent.Vue.$mount (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1839
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3544
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
merged @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3301
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6047
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5948
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6471
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3118
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5972
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5919
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6510
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3939
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4060
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4473
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4462
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4067
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8409
(anonymous) @ main.ts?bc82:8
./src/main.ts @ app.js:5941
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
fn @ app.js:130
1 @ app.js:6015
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:767
(anonymous) @ app.js:902
(anonymous) @ app.js:905
Show 10 more frames
Demo.vue?96da:47 *** this actually ran
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@phosphor/widgets": "^1.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.8.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

#### router.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from './views/Home.vue';
import Demo from './components/Demo.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
    },
    {
      path: '/demo',
      name: 'demo',
      component: Demo,
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue'),
    },
  ],
});
```

#### Demo.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="demo">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    {{ dpanel }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { Widget, DockPanel } from '@phosphor/widgets';

@Component
export default class Demo extends Vue {
  @Prop() private title!: string;

  // apparently with typescript variant of vue, instance variables
  // are the equivalent of the vue 'data' object's attributes...
  dpanel:DockPanel = new DockPanel();

  components:any

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.components = {
      DockPanel,
    };
  }

  mounted() {
    const widget1 = new Widget();
    widget1.addClass('content');
    widget1.addClass('blue');
    widget1.title.label = 'Blue';
    widget1.title.closable = true;

    const widget2 = new Widget();
    widget2.addClass('content');
    widget2.addClass('red');
    widget2.title.label = 'Red';
    widget2.title.closable = true;

    this.dpanel.id = 'main';

    this.dpanel.addWidget(widget1);
    this.dpanel.addWidget(widget2);
    this.dpanel.update();
    console.log('*** this actually ran');
  }

  static setupPanels():void {
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="less">
.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
}


.red {
  background: #E74C3C;
}


.yellow {
  background: #F1C40F;
}


.green {
  background: #27AE60;
}


.blue {
  background: #3498DB;
}


.p-DockTabPanel {
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}


.p-DockTabPanel > .p-StackedPanel {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


.p-DockPanel-overlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border: 1px dashed black;
}


.p-DockPanel-overlay.p-mod-root-top,
.p-DockPanel-overlay.p-mod-root-left,
.p-DockPanel-overlay.p-mod-root-right,
.p-DockPanel-overlay.p-mod-root-bottom,
.p-DockPanel-overlay.p-mod-root-center {
  border-width: 2px;
}


.p-TabBar {
  min-height: 24px;
  max-height: 24px;
}


.p-TabBar-header {
  display: none;
}


.p-TabBar-footer {
  flex: 0 0 1px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
}


.p-TabBar-content {
  min-width: 0;
  align-items: flex-end;
}


.p-TabBar-tab {
  flex: 0 1 125px;
  min-height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  min-width: 35px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background: #E5E5E5;
  font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


.p-TabBar-tab:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}


.p-TabBar-tab.p-mod-current {
  min-height: 23px;
  max-height: 23px;
  background: white;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}


.p-TabBar-tab:hover:not(.p-mod-current) {
  background: #F0F0F0;
}


.p-TabBar-tabIcon,
.p-TabBar-tabText,
.p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon {
  line-height: 20px;
}


.p-TabBar-tab.p-mod-closable > .p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon {
  margin-left: 4px;
}


.p-TabBar-tab.p-mod-closable > .p-TabBar-tabCloseIcon:before {
  content: '\f00d';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.p-TabBar-tab.p-mod-drag-image {
  min-height: 23px;
  max-height: 23px;
  min-width: 125px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transform: translateX(-40%) translateY(-58%);
}
```

What's causing this error, and how do I resolve it (so I can correctly render the widgets for example, as shown [here](http://phosphorjs.github.io/examples/dockpanel/))?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PhosphorJS, so I can only provide an explanation of what's going on.

It looks like you're trying to render a DockPanel instance in the template by doing `{{ dpanel }}`. This won't work. This "mustache syntax" is for rendering basic data types like strings and numbers, if you render an object in this way then Vue will render the JSON representation of that object by calling [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) on it; in this case the `dpanel` object contains circular references so this will fail.

I just skimmed the [PhosphorJS docs](https://phosphorjs.github.io/phosphor/api/widgets/classes/dockpanel.html). It looks like PhosphorJS is not a Vue component library, so you'll have to insert the DockPanel node into the DOM yourself, probably in the `mounted` hook.

```
mounted() {
  this.$el.appendChild(this.dpanel.node)
},

destroyed() {
  this.dpanel.dispose()
}
```

Again, I'm not familiar with PhosphorJS so this might not be the most correct advice.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution seems to get rid of the circular structure error, but the widgets are still not rendering correctly in the browser. I am trying to replicate [this example](http://phosphorjs.github.io/examples/dockpanel/)